# What happens with the original commits between <upstream> and <branch> after a "git rebase --onto"?

Tags: git

On the [git man page for rebase](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) you can find one example for rebasing branches.

```
                        H---I---J topicB
                       /
              E---F---G  topicA
             /
A---B---C---D  master
```

The command `git rebase --onto master topicA topicB` would yield ...

```
             H'--I'--J'  topicB
            /
            | E---F---G  topicA
            |/
A---B---C---D  master
```

... which is quite reasonable as far as I understand rebasing. Unfortunately the next example shows a different output. Basically it describes how rebasing can be used to remove commits:

```
E---F---G---H---I---J  topicA
```

According to the man page calling `git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA` would yield ...

```
E---H'---I'---J'  topicA
```

..., and thus, "remove `F` and `G`".

But actually I don't see a big difference between the first and the second example:

```
        H---I topicA
       /
  F---G topicA~3
 /
E topicA~5
```

So the result should be more like

```
 H'--I'--J'  topicB
/
| F---G  
|/
E
```

Are `F` and `G` still there or are they really removed? At least `gitk` shows me `F` and `G` and even `H`, `I` and `J`. Are this unreachable commits? Will they be "garbage-collected" after some time? Or will there be forever on my disk (even pushed to a remote). Can this be applied on the first example as well? Are `H`, `I` and `J` still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not deleted, the commits are still there and if you know the commit you can check them out, tag them, create a branch etc. the git reflog command can help find them.

If nothing refers to them they will eventually be garbage collected. [This](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) page tells you more about that. By default it is after 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

The original `E---F---G---H---I---J` are *all* still there afterwards. Rebasing isn't capable of changing anything. Think of it more like generating a patch for each commit under rebase, which is then applied to the new branch under creation. `F` and `G` aren't removed; the change from `G` to `H` is replayed on top of `E`, creating `H'`. Then the change from `H` to `I` is replayed on top of that new `H'`, creating `I'`. In the end, the branch - which is just a pointer - is repointed to `J'`, and the original branch disappears from view, because nothing points to any part of it now.